# Getting Database Content

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I made a database in phpmyadmin and then uploaded a database (.sql file) to it. I made a table of 'users' in the sql file. I want to see the user's passwords which are not in plain text. I am also attaching a screenshot below:-

[image]

Comment: this is expected --- user password should be encrypted

Comment: I agee. But I have installed this script in localhost and this password is mine only. I forgot it and want to see it. Is it possible?

Comment: No, it is not possible

Answer (score 3):

The `$2y$10$Py6NkdN/5c40J8w1NGpDc.` at the beginning indicates the passwords are encrypted with bcrypt (the 2, with the y indicating which bcrypt variant) with cost setting 10 and a salt of `Py6NkdN/5c40J8w1NGpDc.`.  This is a one-way encryption; there is no way to calculate the original password from this encrypted value.  To check if a password matches, you encrypt it with that bcrypt algorithm and salt and see if it produces the `sfEW40...` value.

Comment: You mean hashed, not encrypted, but yes

Comment: I didn't get what you are saying. Can you please elaborate.